# What difference does the _(underscore) before the function call add() make?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, indexeddb

```
$.each(data, function(i){
        _(catalog.add(this));//iterating through each object in objectStore
});
```

I was wondering what difference does it make if i exclude the underscore before the function call.

**Update**

The OP is referring to the [jquery indexeddb plugin](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/blob/master/jquery.indexeddb.js).

Comment: What's the definition of function `_`? It's not from JQuery; perhaps it's from underscore.js but it doesn't really ring a bell here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It calls a function called `_` and passes the result of the expression `catalog.add(this)` as the first and only argument.

That function is quite likely the one defined by the library you can download from [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/), which is another in a series of libraries that lack intention revealing variable names.

Comment: Please don't sound so pejorative about Underscore; using a simple variable name might be controversial but it's a more reasonable way to extend a language than to cause havoc by modifying builtin prototypes.

Comment: It isn't a "simple" variable name, it is an obscure variable name. It doesn't even *look* like a variable name to many people (which is probably why this question was asked in the first place).

Comment: Would you argue that `$` as in jQuery's (and others) case is better or even _good_ to use? Personally, I much prefer `$` over `jQuery`, yet I can't stand `_` - I think it's messy.

Comment: `$` is marginally better than `_` (since an underline is used by some editors to mark errors/warnings and it is hard to tell the difference between an underlined space and an underscore character) but not so much better that I'd call it good.

Comment: Also the `_` is used in several languages to mark private members

Answer (score 0):

http://underscorejs.org/#chaining

I'm not exactly sure what its doing for you, but here's the doc.

Comment: it was a sample code i was going through that uses as a jquery plugin to deal with indexedDB. https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/blob/master/example/index.html

Comment: catalog is an object called an object store which is a type of table in indexedDB. catalog.add(this) does nothing but add each value while iterating through a json file. All i want to know is the reason behind placing the underscore there. Might be a silly question. I'm a newbie. Pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Short answer: Yes, no different. Remove it.

From your source js file, `_` is a function name for logging result of promise object. So you have to remove it in production code if you don't care what `add` method return. `add` method should return newly created keys.

To me, those `$`, `i`, `_` and `this` does not make sense.

`add(this)` is very scary. what is `this`?

Comment: maybe i should have posted the whole code. Here it is   https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/blob/master/example/index.html

Comment: @Kyaw - you asked "What is `this`?" It's a JavaScript keyword as explained [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: `this` could be some object that cannot be cloned, like DOMElement. In that case Indexeddb shall throw DataCloneError. My opinion, `add(this)` should generally be avoided.